# Django: accessing properties between classes and performing math on them

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm currently learning Django...

Upon making a pledge, the user can choose a reward. The reward has a value and a deductible value. For example: there may be a reward worth $50 but only $40 of it is deductible. A user can donate the $50 or more, so if they donate $100, everything is deductible except for $10.

I have two classes: "Pledge" and "Reward" and need to do a bit of math using a new field in "Reward" to determine how much of a pledge is deductible.

```
class Pledge(models.Model):

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project')
    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=10,
        default=D('0.00'))
    reward = models.ForeignKey('Reward',blank=True,null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

I simply copied the reward property above in hopes of pulling not_taxable from Reward, but I get this error: projects.Pledge.not_taxable: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Pledge.not_taxable' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Pledge.reward'.

```
    not_taxable = models.ForeignKey('Reward',blank=True,null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

...

```
    def get_deductible_total(self):
        return (self.amount - self.not_taxable)

    @property
    def deductible_total(self):
        return self.get_deductible_total()
```

...

```
class Reward(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pledge_level = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    deductible = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10,default='0')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

...

```
    def get_not_taxable(self):
        return (self.pledge_level - self.deductible)

    @property
    def not_taxable(self):
        return self.get_not_taxable()
```

Comment: Or should I change my thinking and make a:
    class Deduction(models.Model):

Comment: The reason for your troubles is that you are trying to add two foreign keys in Pledge from Reward. A table can only have one foreign key of another. You have already defined not_taxable in Reward, so you don't need to create an additional one in Pledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @postoronnim for noticing and explaining that... I removed it and then added it to the admin.py which I had also neglected.